# Can a literature review be a "master's thesis"?

Tags: masters, thesis, literature-review

I have selected a single question for my master's thesis, within my field of Foreign Language Teaching. Most papers I have read contain just short literature reviews providing some background for a research study that occupied most of the writer's time. I think I could understand my question better if I focusing all of my effort on creating a 100-200 page literature review, examining and critiquing all existing literature on the subject, rather than on trying to come up with some new results.

Can a master's thesis be comprised of just a literature review? Do journals publish literature reviews on their own?

Comment: What is your area of study?

Answer (score 15):

At least in my Faculty (of Computer Science), a master thesis can be "just" a literature review. A literature review can be an important contribution, and is part of what is usually called [secondary research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_research).

However, you should consider performing a [systematic literature review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_review), which is a literature review comprising several analytic and precise steps to enhance the reliability of the study. A systematic literature review is a time consuming research activity but a very useful one. Please verify that such a review has not already been conducted recently, before starting it by your own.

[Systematic reviews are publishable research](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22systematic+review%22) and often get many citations. As for thesis, I think that any publishable research activity can be a student's master thesis. *However, ask your (potential) advisor*.

Comment: (+1) Yes, I strongly appreciate literature reviews. It is not a trivial contribution to accurately summarize the history, state of the art, and current challenges of a discipline. Doing a systematic literature helps with the quality and feasibility of producing the literature review.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking two different questions here.

- Yes, you can publish a high-quality literature review in some, but not all, journals. However, many journals also *solicit* such reviews rather than take them automatically, and many will have length restrictions associated with them. So check with the journal before you start working!
- As for a master's thesis, that depends a lot on the requirements of your field. In the humanities, you would probably have to do some searches for primary references, but a large-scale literature review is an important part of such a work. In the sciences and engineering, however, you are much less likely to be able to submit such a thesis. The usual standards there require more original work than can typically be accomplished with a literature review.

Answer (score 0):

A literature review with well-defined research questions that provides a synthesis of high-quality literature is considered very useful research. Generally, such reviews present a taxonomy of the domain, summarize the contributions and furnish them in an abstract manner from different aspects involved.
A good quality review gets many citations, and it provides a very useful stepping stone for new researchers in a given area.
Thus, it can certainly be considered as an MS thesis.

Comment: But it depends, of course, on what an advisor or a university will permit.

Comment: Though there are different contexts and meanings of the word, often when people say "research" they mean "original research". Reviews are certainly *useful* to the research process, but may not be considered themselves *research*.